# How to change the background color of the UItableview cell accesoryType?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using an UITableviewCell's Accessory type checkmark property to distinguish the selected cell with the other cells, but I tend to get this weird background view below it ?

```
        cell!.selectionStyle = .none
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell?.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#866bff")
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F8F9FA")
        cell!.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: optionsSize)
        cell!.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#484D57")  //optionsTextColor ?? tint ?? cell!.textLabel!.textColor
        cell!.textLabel!.textAlignment = optionsTextAlignment ?? cell!.textLabel!.textAlignment
        cell!.textLabel!.text = "\(options[indexPath.row])"
        //cell!.accessoryType = indexPath.row == selectedIndex ? .checkmark : .none

        if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex){

            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }else{
            cell?.accessoryType = .none
        }

        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = indexPath.row == selectedIndex ? UIColor(hexString: "#866bff") : tint


        return cell!
```

[image]

Comment: Try change cell background color to match cell contentView background color

Comment: Why is `cell` optional? Why are you inconsistently using `cell!.` and `cell?` ? Do yourself a favor and avoid an optional cell.

Comment: "below" on what axis? x,y, or z?

Comment: Actually I am using a library from Github for the dropDown effect and had this issue and started digging into the code. Tableview was created already, but yeah I will try fixing the inconsistency.

Comment: Changing the Background color of the cell fixed it, thanks a lot @Tj3n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment, change the cell's `backgroundColor` to match cell's contentView `backgroundColor` fixed it since accessoryView is not related to cell's contentView and it will use cell background color as it's background color